# Java- How is using an interface for callbacks advantageous?

Tags: java

I am trying to get a grasp on the concept of using interfaces for callbacks and I feel that I have a basic understanding.

I was introduced to interfaces through the example of processing data in a collection--you can iterate through a collection of Interface objects, and each element in the collection implements that Interface in its own way.

However, I am now learning that this has some limitations, including that Library classes cannot implement the methods (what others?). How do callbacks solve these limitations? (I understand how it solves the problem I described). Thanks for the help, having a tough time really grasping this.

Comment: What does _Library classes cannot implement the methods_ mean?

Comment: @AndrewS: I assume that OP is referring to the fact that in Java, if you're using an existing library with a `Foo` class, there's no way for you to define your own `IFoo` interface that the existing `Foo` class will implement -- even if all of the method signatures are the same -- which in turn means that you can't define your own `MyFoo` class that implements the same interface. (There are some languages that are more permissive in this regard.)

Answer (score 1):

> How do callbacks solve these limitations?

They mostly don't.

We use callbacks when we have an asynchronous interaction pattern; for example, if we want to send an HTTP request without tying up our thread, then we need a callback to handle the response when it comes.

In such a situation, we're willing to put up with the awkwardness of these limitations.

(Keep in mind that none of the limitations mean "X can't be done". For example, you write that "Library classes cannot implement the methods", which is true, but it's easy to write a callback object that operates on another object. Java 8 has made this even easier than it used to be; something like `(response) -> responseList.add(response)` is a complete callback object that saves the response into the existing `responseList`.)